# Pass through USB device to guest using VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I bought a usb dongle which I intend to use in Ubuntu 10.04. The problem is I haven't been able to find any Linux drivers for it which has prompted me to find another solution: Virtualbox.

I intend to run Windows XP as guest and plug in the dongle which will run inside Windows easily. The challenge for me is in making sure Ubuntu gets the connection too and I do all my web development stuff inside Linux. Windows has to be just a gateway.

Thanks

Comment: You may be happier getting your USB dongle to work in Ubuntu - please give us hardware details to help you on this.

Comment: thanks, but how do i find out exactly? all i can tell right now is that i'm using a Sony Vaio VGN C250N...

Comment: plug in your dongle and run "lsusb" from command line and post its output here.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the feature you're looking for is called `usb-passthrough` and is only available in the closed source version of VirtualBox.

```
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp11184832
```